# Insert the value of a JavaScript function to an SQL Server database

Tags: javascript, sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add a JavaScript variable in an SQL Server database database (run an SQL query or [stored procedure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored_procedure))? If so, how?

Comment: not sure what you mean - I would think you can insert whatever value you can output - can you explain with a little more detail?

Comment: i want save value of some javascript variable within a function in sql server database. like save last position of one image that changed by user.

Comment: I see this question almost everyday now on SO.

Comment: Is this question restricted to Microsoft *SQL Server* or is it for any SQL database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With JavaScript only, no you cannot (unless you're using [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) of course).

The point is, you'll need some **server-side** code to interact with your database. You can use JavaScript in the browser to make an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) call to a server-side script ([PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), Node.js, etc.) that performs the interaction with the database.

Comment: This would be your most ideal solution. Node.js is pretty new and it would make sense to get your hands dirty on it and learn it. Otherwise, you can use Ajax to send Client Side calls to a server script and your server script can save or update the data in your database.

Answer (score 1):

You can not access the database from JavaScript. You need to send your data to PHP, [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) or [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET) or whatever you are using to implement the [back end](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_and_back_ends#Computer_science).

Comment: no, AJAX will invoke your server and the server will do all the stuff. this means you are sending your javascript data to server using ajax

Comment: yes, agree AJAX is javascript... which make a http request.. but it not invoke any database without your server side implementation. The invoking db is mainly done by the server side technology.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Ajax to post to a web service of some sort (or any other server side script) to pass the JavaScript value. The web service would access the database and save it...

Answer (score 0):

Set value of variable in the hidden field and get value of that field at server side when submit form and save it into the database....

Comment: With a JS set of a hidden field, the server won't access it without a repost, and it won't save without a repost - which I believe in this case defeats the purpose...

Answer (score 0):

You can easily [access a database from JavaScript in Node.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules#wiki-database).

If you're doing it from the browser, you'll most definitely need some kind of mid-tier service which translates HTTP queries to the relevant database driver (you can write that in any language you want - [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP), JavaScript, [ASP.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET), etc.).